# Powershell, Adding core 2k16 to domain issue

Tags: windows, powershell, server

So, I'm sure I'm making a rookie mistake here. That being said...
I'm attempting to join a server core edition to my domain. I'm doing it like I've done others, and legacy 2k12 systems as well. It's just not working, and I'm not sure why.

I have all firewalls (hardware and software) disabled, I have DNS servers up and running with an updated cache. All IP routing and domain name function is working through PS... This being said, I'm inputting the command and getting this back. No matter what I do I can't get it to work.
Bubble.local is the Domain??
DC-NUG1 is the DC with ADDS and forest root.

```
PS C:\Windows\System32\en-US> Add-Computer -domainname DC-NUG1.bubble.local 
   -Credential AD\adminuser Add-Computer : Computer 'core-nug' failed to join 
  domain 'DC-NUG1.bubble.local'
  from its current workgroup 'WORKGROUP' with following error message: The
  specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.
  At line:1 char:1
```

Comment: is DNS properly configured? Can you do a nslookup for that domain? Also are you supposed to connect to the domain "DC-NUG1.bubble.local" or should it be "bubble.local"? It looks like you accidently put the domain controller FQDN instead of the domian name.

Comment: @user1451070 you should add that as an answer, basically `Add-Computer -DomainName bubble.local -Server DC-NUG1.bubble.local` seems to be what OP is after